# Change the grid columns based on the selected tile

Tags: angular, grid

I am working some dashboard component in the angular app, i am new to angular

Based on the tile I have selected my grid need to change

My current code is

in Component.ts

```
    tileId: any = '1';
public appliedcolumns =[{
    name: 'EmployeeId',
    type: 'number',
    sortable: true,
    hidden: false,
    displayName: 'Employee Id'
  },
  {
      name: 'EmployeeName',
      type: 'string',
      sortable: true,
      hidden: false,
      displayName: 'Employee Name',
  },
  {
    name: 'AppliedDate',
    type: 'dateTime',
    sortable: true,
    hidden: false,
    displayName: 'Approved Date',
  }] 

public approvedcolumns =[{
    name: 'EmployeeId',
    type: 'number',
    sortable: true,
    hidden: false,
    displayName: 'Employee Id'
  },
  {
      name: 'EmployeeName',
      type: 'string',
      sortable: true,
      hidden: false,
      displayName: 'Employee Name',
  },
  {
    name: 'ApprovedDate',
    type: 'dateTime',
    sortable: true,
    hidden: false,
    displayName: 'Approved Date',

  }} 
ngOnInit() {
this.getDetails("1");
}

getDetails(tileid: string) {
//getting data from backend
}

//on tile click event sending the new tile id to getdata
onClickMe(tile){
this.getDetails(tileId);
}
```

Html look like

```
<div class="panel"(click)="onClickMe(tile)"></div>

<div *ngIf="tileId == 1">
        <custum-grid-view class="" [jsonObject]="jsonData" [totalNoOfRecords]="totalNoOfRecords" [gridOptions]="gridOptions" [gridActions]="actions" [staticColumns]="appliedcolumns" (actionsEvent)="actionsEvent($event)"></custum-grid-view>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="tileId == 2">
        <custum-grid-view class="" [jsonObject]="jsonData" [totalNoOfRecords]="totalNoOfRecords" [gridOptions]="gridOptions" [gridActions]="actions" [staticColumns]="approvedcolumns" (actionsEvent)="actionsEvent($event)"></custum-grid-view>
      </div>
```

All my code is working fine for me,
But i don't want the hard code values in my code

i have 4-5 tiles in my dash board and same 4-5 column objects in same Component.ts
how can i move them out from y Component and access from out side

Answer (score 0):

Move them in a `Service` if there is no server that can provide that data to you.

Then you can make use of the dependency injection and get the data like:

```
export class YourComponent {
    public appliedcolumns = [];
    public approvedcolumns = [];
    ...
    constructor(private dataService: DataService){
         this.appliedcolumns = this.dataService.getAppliedColumns();
         this.approvedcolumns = this.dataService.getApprovedColumns();
         //...etc
    }   
}
```

**Edit**: In the service you can have a method to retrieve the data based on the index.

```
// Inside DataService, for applied columns lets say
getAppliedColumnsDetailsByID(id: number){
   return this.appliedcolumns[id] ? this.appliedcolumns[id] : null;
}
```

You can do same for the other data or combine them in a single function.

Comment: How can i pass this , dont want to hardcode this number 
ngOnInit() {
this.getDetails("1");
}